# How do I reference multiple structured tables in a sumif or sumifs in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am wishing to reference multiple structured tables (one on each sheet) to sum up $dollar values by category .

I did sumifs practice from microsoft, which did not use structured tables. It referenced the worksheets and cells.   (see the excercise) as an image. Here is the formula used: [image: screen shot of cells]
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&F$3:F$7 & "'!"&"D$3:D$7"),INDIRECT("'"&F$3:F$7&"'!"&"C$3:C$7"),H3))
This worked fine.

Then I did the single page, single table formula with the structured table:

```
=SUMIFS(tbl_Dir_Inv_6855468[Value],tbl_Dir_Inv_6855468[Category],[@Category])
```

This worked also.
Then I thought I would be able to add the other tables using the Indirect Function.
I made a list of my table names that I want accessed: in address: I11:I16. tbl1  tbl2  etc.
I tried to work with the practice formula and adapt it: This is what I tried.

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("&I$11:I$16" &"[Value]"INDIRECT("&I$11:I$16" &"[Category]",[@Category]))
```

I also tried  - adding back the single apostrophe
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&I$11:I$16"'" &"[Value]"INDIRECT("'"&I$11:I$16"'" &"[Category]",[@Category]))
Neither of these worked.

I am not sure if it is a syntax error because of the apostrophes wrong or is it that I can't just put a table name in using the Indirect function. I am totally new to Structured Tables and not very skilled at excel. I hope that I have asked this question properly so as not to waste peoples time here.
Sorry, I also couldn't figure out how to tag the code as code here. I thought that it was just 4 enters before the code.
Thank you For your Help.

Comment: You _can_ use table names in `INDIRECT`.  Eg if `I6` contains the name of a table, and that table has a column called `Value`, then `=SUM(INDIRECT(I6&"[Value]"))` would sum that column.  The tables don't have to be on the same sheet, and the INDIRECT doesn't change if they arn't

Comment: That said, it's not entirely clear  how your data is layed out, so I can't provide a full answer ATM, until it is clear

Comment: You seem to be missing an aggregating function in your attempt. `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(I$11:I$16&"[Value]"),INDIRECT(I$11:I$16&"[Category]"),[@Category]))` should work fine.

Comment: @chrisneilsen,   Thank you.  What you changed did work.  It looks like I didn't need to make a string of my Cell addresses of the Tablenames.  When I used the Worksheet names instead of tables, I needed to use apostrophes. I am trying to figure out why the difference.  Is there still a way to upvote your answer?  I haven't been on here in quite a while and can't find it. TKS A LOT.

Comment: @JosWoolley  I thank you for your answer and the change that you made.  What you changed did work. It looks like I didn't need to make a string of my Cell addresses of the Tablenames. Re: "missing an aggregating function"? I believe that the First argument is the aggregating function then the result of this formula goes into a completely different table to the row named "Value" where it then autopopulates all of the columns according to the category.  I hope that makes send.  Is there still a way to upvote your answer? I haven't been on here in quite a while and can't find it. TKS A LOT.